# r - Use tab as part of seperator

Tags: r, string

I am trying to print a string followed by ": [tab]" and then a number. The relevant part of my code looks like:

```
print(paste("Name",5, sep=":\t"))
```

But this gives me

> "Name:\t5"

. I have tried:

```
print(paste("Name",5, sep=cat(":\t")))
```

but this gives me:

```
Error in paste("Name", 5, sep = cat(":\t")) : 
  invalid separator
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is related to the issue discussed in [this email thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-January/085702.html) but I don't understand the solution.

Comment: `cat(paste("Name",5, sep=":\t"))`?

Comment: Yup. Thank you! Can you explain what `cat` is doing? Also, it prints `NULL` at the end. How do I get rid of that?

Comment: See `?cat` - it concatenates and prints... also non-printable characters like your tab.

Comment: @Adam_G I don't see `NULL` printed when running luke's code...

Comment: I had a `print` statement in there also. I did some more reading and saw it was redundant. Problem solved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can go as follows:

```
cat("Name","\t", 5, "\n")
```

When you need help on a function, just type in the name of that function in your R GUI preceded by `?`, eg `?cat`.

Answer (score 6):

**there is no need to use cat.**

this function

```
paste("Name",5, sep=":\t")
```

already works however when you "print" it, it shows the tab as ANSI sequence hence it shows the "Name:\t5".

Cat is only outputting it to show the effect.

if you store the value of paste function in a variable and write it to a file or View anywhere you will notice that no escape character is present.

```
output<-paste("Name",5, sep=":\t")
```

If you are in R-Studio use View command to see the actual output

```
View(output)
```

To know why R studio does that read this in print.defaults of R documentation

> Single-byte locales
>
> If a non-printable character is encountered during output, it is represented as one of the ANSI escape sequences (\a, \b, \f, \n, \r, \t, \v, \ and \0