# Using tabs in a ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use tab in a legend in a ggplot.
I tried

```
paste('a', 'b', sep='\t')
```

but then I get

```
"a\tb"
```

Comment: as far as i can see, your question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427152/r-use-tab-as-part-of-seperator

Comment: @OP if the issue is a ggplot legend, I would suggest including that in your question. `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = cyl)) + geom_point() + labs(color = "legend\twith tab")` shows the problem nicely.

Comment: @D.J That's not relevant. This question asks about ggplot legend title, not simply printing tab into the console. @OP I can get ggplot to parse new line (`\n`) but not tab. Why? I don't know.

Comment: I does not know much but this seems not to be ggplot specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923852/include-t-character-in-facet-strip-text-with-custom-labeller and https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1144. Hadley's answer: "It doesn't look like R supports tab characters in graphics devices"